# How to access past DrupalCon website that requires password?

Tags: community-official-site

I want to browse DrupalCon websites to learn stuff from past DrupalCon.

Below is partial list:

- Chicago 2011    March   http://chicago2011.drupal.org/
- Copenhagen  2010    August  http://cph2010.drupal.org/
- San Francisco   2010    April   http://sf2010.drupal.org/
- Paris   2009    September   http://paris2009.drupalcon.org/
- Washington, D.C.    2009    March   http://dc2009.drupalcon.org/
- Szeged  2008    August  http://szeged2008.drupalcon.org/
- Boston  2008    March   http://boston2008.drupalcon.org/

However, a lot of them (e.g Copenhagen, D.C, Szeged, Boston) require user and pass to login. Not sure why some Con are open to public, some are closed.

Is there a way to obtain an account to access them? or Is there an alternative way to find content of those DrupalCon?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason they're password-protected is due to [a critical security vulnerability](http://drupal.org/node/1021210) in the version of [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) run on those sites. There's an [open issue](http://drupal.org/node/1022346) about it, and only the DrupalCon sites updated to a secure version of Webform are allowed to remain up.

In order to gain access to the ones that are still in lockdown, I'd comment on that issue to see what you can do to help get them updated. Otherwise, you can use the [Internet Wayback Machine](http://www.archive.org/web/web.php) to access [Archive.org](http://archive.org)'s cached copy.